# How to remove rEFInd drivers completely from my ubuntu?

Tags: grub2, refind

How can I permanently get rid of so many rEFInd entries that I created while trying to fix grub? I want to completely remove rEFInd from my system.

My PC is a dual boot with win 10 and ubuntu 16.04.

Here is an image of my grub menu

[image: image of my grub menu]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to completely remove rEFInd, do the following:

```
sudo dpkg -P refind
sudo rm -rf /boot/efi/EFI/refind
sudo update-grub
```

Depending on how you installed rEFInd, the first of those commands may return an error. The second deletes the rEFInd files. The third causes GRUB to rebuild its boot menu, which should omit the rEFInd entries.

If you want to leave rEFInd installed but remove the unnecessary drivers, you can remove the ones you don't want individually via `rm`, then run `sudo update-grub` to rebuild the GRUB menu.